# Parts for a 4 Candle set

Tags: design

I want to build several stands with 4 candles.
Here's my plan from bottom to top

- 3 round 1x1 bricks for the base
- a [palm top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2566&C=2#T=P&C=2) to branch into 4 parts
- a round 1x1 brick on each of the 4 bars
- a [pin holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=20482&C=34#T=P&C=34) on  top of each of those
- a [candle flame](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=37775&C=0#T=P&C=0) tucked into the pin holder.

I don't have these parts yet, so I'm hoping someone can verify this will work before I buy them.
If not, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The four round 1x1 bricks will fit, but I don’t think the bars of the palm top are long enough to reach the hole in the top of the bricks. You might need to fill each brick with a Technic half pin (or substitute the bricks entirely as the pins have a stud on top of them already).

Comment: Indeed, the length of the palmtop bars is **not** enough to reach the narrow part of the 1x1 round bricks. Some 1x1 round *plates* might help. I'd go for a design using two 1x3 plates (stacked in a "X" shape) instead of the palmtop.

Comment: Would designing this in Stud.io or Mecabricks help?

Comment: Sorry, I keep wanting to make a [2 Ronnies joke here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pV1IP4N9ajg)...

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Well, of course, have some [fork handles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x81sub1).

Answer (score 8):

In principle, this will work although as D M notes (assuming a non-inverted build), the 1x1 bricks won't attach to the palm top correctly as they aren't long enough - a 1x1 round plate with hole on the bottom will help - either the same colour as the candle or as a part of the holder.

You might find that the candles are too close together for you as they would end up touching:

[image: Candles on palm top]

If you aren't worried about stability, by inverting the the 1x1 round bricks and resting the pin-holders upside down for a more "used" look, however the pin holders aren't secured:

[image: Inverted elements]

Other options you might consider include using:

- The very old [5x5 Propeller with 4 blades](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3461), very limited colour set
- Plate Round 4x4 with hole
- Two 1x3 plates stacked crossways, with 1x1 plates to provide additional support and conformity (as IvanSanchez suggests)
- [Plate, Modified 3x3 Cross](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15397), only available in a limited colour set, but available in at least black, brown and reddish brown (as Matthew Jensen suggests)
- [Axle Connector Hub with 4 bars](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=68888) and four [Bar Holder with clip](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11090) to hold inverted pin holders

[image: Some alternate builds]

The Haunted House set uses a [Pearl Gold Technic Knob Cog](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32072&idColor=115#T=C&C=115) in its chandelier, shown with the Candle element:

[image]

Comment: A relatively new element, the [Plate 3 x 3 Cross](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15397&name=Plate,%20Modified%203%20x%203%20Cross&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C) would be a bit more compact and stable than 1 x 3 plates, although it doesn't exist in as many colours.

Answer (score 7):

LEGO has dedicated element for "candle wax" - [Minifigure, Utensil Candle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=37762). This may be another option.

[image]

Its diameter is smaller than of 1x1 round brick, so you can put 4 of them together on single 2x2 round plate without touching. Here is an example, where you can see the difference in diameter (1x1 round plate is same as 1x1 round brick). Parts used in pictured build are listed [here](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75981-2).

[image]

Comment: Nice, and the base of the candle fits inside any hollow stud. I'm thinking [2476 2x2 modified plate with technic pin on bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2476) could work nicely.